# box-shadow and box-radius not working in IE9 for the particular screens

Tags: css

I'm facing a problem regarding `box-shadow` and `box-radius` css properties, that aren't correctly working on some particular pages.

How can I solve this?

Please help me.

Below is the `css` I'm using

```
.button a { 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
-moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
box-shadow:         4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
margin-left:30px;
line-height: 20px;

padding:10px 10px;
background-color:#009e57;
display:block;
color:#fff;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;

 }
```

Comment: Can you share your problem on Jsfiddle?

Comment: Plase post jsfiddle example or URL to your website, if it's already online.

Comment: css works fine for other screens, but having problem in 2screens

Comment: There shouldn't be features that are blocked on different resolutions. Make sure you dont have any @media query that will turn off the box-shadow and box-radius

Answer (score 1):

Well, try and switch the `button` and `a` tag.

- As far as i know, there is no `box-radius` rule, perhaps you mean `border-radius`?
- `<a href="#"><button>Click Me</button></a>`.
- CSS: `a button { /* Your CSS */}`.
- If you still having issues, Check the site [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS), You can check browser compatibility for every CSS rule.

Comment: yes, it is border-radius only, typing mistake.... Why these both not working for particular pages?

Comment: made sure that you are linking those pages to your CSS file?